# Query of MS Access to Update into SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, ms-access

A legacy application I need to get data from uses a very old Access database (97). The sample code the vendor provides is VB6. :Insert Annoyed Look:

My new app already has a SQL Server database with a schema that largely corresponds to the Access database. So the first thing I want to do in my application is read the access database and dump it SQL Server. Essentially, I want to copy over 4 or 5 tables.

You'd think there would be an easy to follow example to follow for this sort of thing, but my google-fu is failing me trying to find one. I need to do this programatically, rather than thru an upgrade utility.

Comment: SSIS? otherwise: please find an explanation and [code for dumping Data from Access to SQL-Server linked tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37412499/ms-access-application-work-offline/37416358#37416358).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you tag your question .net, i suppose using c# code

The following class is ImportHelper that import from source  to target.

Define ConnectionString for source and target

```
class ImportHelper
{

    //modify connectionstring as needed
    public string SourceConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string DestinationConnectionString { get; set; }

    public ImportHelper(string sourceConnectionString, string destinationConnectionString)
    {
        SourceConnectionString = sourceConnectionString;
        DestinationConnectionString = destinationConnectionString;
    }
    public void Import(string sourceTable, string targetTable = null)
    {
        using (var sourceConnection = new OleDbConnection(SourceConnectionString))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(targetTable)) targetTable = sourceTable;
            sourceConnection.Open();

            // Perform an initial count on the destination table.
            var commandRowCount = new OleDbCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + sourceTable, sourceConnection);
            long countStart = Convert.ToInt32(commandRowCount.ExecuteScalar());
            Console.WriteLine("Source Table [{0}] has {1} rows", sourceTable, countStart);

            // Get data from the source table  
            var commandSourceData = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM " + sourceTable, sourceConnection);
            var reader = commandSourceData.ExecuteReader();

            //---------------
            using (SqlConnection destinationConnection = new SqlConnection(DestinationConnectionString))
            {
                destinationConnection.Open();

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(destinationConnection))
                {
                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = targetTable;

                    try
                    {
                        // Write from the source to the destination.
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
                        Console.WriteLine("Sucess Importing " + sourceTable);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                }//using
            }//using
        }//using
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
//modify connectionstring as needed
    //Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\mydatabase.mdb;User Id=admin;Password=; //access 97..2000
    string SourceConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\database1.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    string DestinationConnectionString = @"Data Source=xxxx;Initial Catalog=test;user=xxx;password=xxx;";
   new ImportHelper(SourceConnectionString, DestinationConnectionString)
     .Import("table1","test1");
```

Answer (score 0):

User SQL Server's built in Data Import function and import the data directly from Access into SQL Server.

Take a look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

There are several steps involved, but I assume you're only doing it once and this is the easiest way to bring Access data into SQL Server.

If you need to do this repeatedly (i.e. once a week or on some other repeated schedule), setting up an SSIS package is the way to go.

Comment: I am not doing this only once alas. I'm doing this at application initialization so if I could kick this off as a process, I'd be okay with that, but I don't even know the name of the database until I'm running.